# Select a random li using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a random `li` element with jQuery and change its class.
Most of the time it will change the class on one but other times two, sometimes none at all. I am using the code below to get my random `li`,

```
var selection = $('#options li');
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * selection.length) + 1);
$('#options li:eq('+ (rand) +')').addClass('selected');
```

I have 3 `li`'s.

Comment: `Math.random()` has a range of 0-0.999ish.  Mathematically 0.999*3 is approx 2.997.  Then you floor that and you got 2.  Then you add 1, and you get 3.  3 is outside the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selection` should contain an array of li's. I'd just grab a random one of those instead of using an index selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const selection = $('li');
  const randLi = selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];  
  $(randLi).addClass('selected');
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uds6kf63/1/) to demonstrate.

...and here's [one more](https://jsfiddle.net/uds6kf63/5/) that uses the above code to select a random li every half second so you can more easily see the random selection.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my original question. I want it to happen on click. Here is a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/tsh08poL/4/

Comment: @charliework, the event that triggers it doesn't matter. The code above will work in all scenarios (and your fiddle didn't link).

Comment: With a slightly different approach, lines 3 and 4 could also be written as `selection.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)).addClass('selected');`

Comment: OK, @charliework, I see the fiddle now. There's quite a bit wrong with the code, including **lots** of duplicate ids in the markup. My answer above answers your original question.

Comment: Yeah sorry to have to expose you to that code there. Cheers James.